# how to calculate energy produced above power value using integral with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, integral

**What do I have?**

I have df `pd.DataFrame` with **'power'** column and **'timestamp'** column.
I have also a power value who called **'x_power'**

**What do I want?**

I am trying to find out how much energy produced above and below **'x_power'** (for example x_power = 900),
for doing that I think to do an integral of:

[image]

y axis - power

x axis - timestamp

pink area - energy produced above x_power

green area - energy produced below x_power

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

x = df['timestamp'].to_numpy()
y = df['power'].to_numpy()
max = np.max(x)
min = np.min(x)

f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1)  # k=1 gives linear interpolation

f.integral(min , max)
```

output is the area below the graph.

There is an easy way to calculate above and below **'x_power'** without multiple integration?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "integral" and "multiple integration" in this context. Please include some example data (with code), expected output and what you have tried so far in the main post.

Comment: how is it possible that your blue curve goes backwards in time at timestamp 32280 - 32290?

Comment: it is a mistake, but it is not relevant to the question

Comment: Since pandas is ... special about it: The column is indeed a timestamp, and not datetime or float/int (as indicated by your graph)?

Comment: yes it is timestamp, my graph is an example I did manually in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate the area of our plot **over** *x_power* you need
to "move down" your *y* values in such a way that the "new *0*"
is at the *x_power* level.

Then you should clip negative values to zero.

But because you have only **selected** points of the whole plot,
the first step should be to generate the **interpolated** version
of your power production line, e.g. with step of *1* and only then
perform 2 above steps.

The code to do it is:

```
intStep = 1    # Interpolation step
# Interpolated x and y
xInt = np.arange(min, max + 1, intStep)
yInt = (np.interp(xInt, x, y) - x_power).clip(min=0)
```

To see this line, you can run:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(True)
plt.plot(xInt, yInt)
plt.show()
```

And to integrate this function, run your code, but on the above source data:

```
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(xInt, yInt, k=1)
result = f.integral(min, max)
```